# How was this opening title sequence from Atkinson's Maigret made?

Tags: film-techniques, effects, title-sequence, maigret

I've recently become fixed on how superbly the opening titles for **Maigret** (starring Rowan Atkinson) has been made and edited:

Would Rowan have had to have acted this out? As in, recorded a 5-6 second shot of him turning slightly so the camera can zoom into him, or is this all done using CGI or similar?

I can't tell.

(Excuse me, my visual effects knowledge is limited I do admit).

Comment: It looks like a relatively simple effect. You just need to find a small clip of the him moving then you can use basic effect tools (Adobe After Effects for instance) to slow it down, darken it, zoom it and fade in another image. Is it CGI...not exactly, but a special effect, certainly.

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks! I just figure that his move is very robotic, but he is also very good so I wouldn't be surprised if it was just him moving. It looks too.... computerised (in my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible they used a similar multiple-camera setup invented for the Matrix movies.

Imagine a curved frame with a couple of dozen micro-cameras mounted pointing inward, arcing from the above-left of his head to in front of his neck, timed by computer to take simultaneous (or almost simultaneous) images of his upper body in front of a greenscreen. Then all those images are keyed out, taken into editing software, digitally frame-blended to create that few seconds of footage, and color-adjusted to eliminate nearly all the light.

Search terms like "bullet time matrix camera behind-the-scenes" for more info.